# 'HttpInterceptor' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-http-interceptors

I upgraded my new VS2017 angular project to v4.4.6 from the original 4.2.5, then tried to set up an `HttpInterceptor` in my app.module.shared.ts file like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClient,
        HttpInterceptor,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

VS has grayed out the `HttpInterceptor` import command on line 5, and recorded an error on line 28 where I call out the `HttpInterceptor` in the imports list.  A mouseover on the red squiggly line gives me the error message "(TS) 'HttpInterceptor' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

What am I doing wrong?  This is basically a pristine, out-of-the-box angular instance based off the latest VS2017 template, the only thing I did was update angular and run the webpack stuff.

Answer (score 0):

HttpInterceptor is an interface, but 'imports' section awaits a class.

Edit: As far as I can see, the explanation above is not too clear, more in a nutshell:

According to https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

HttpInterceptor is an interface

```
interface HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
}
```

Instead of putting the interface to the "imports: [...]" we have to make a class which implements this interface and put it into the imports, for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor { 
        // bla bla bla
}
```

and then

```
imports: [
...,
AppHttpInterceptor,
...
]
```

Comment: this is probably the most cryptic explanation I have seen on SO

Comment: @ManuChadha thank you for a comment, I added a bit more information to my answer and hope now it is more clear!

Comment: much better now :)